# How do I use os_dir to properly read a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, import, operating-system

Trying to use:

```
os_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(fx))
print(os_dir)


import os, inspect


if '__file__' not in locals():
    fx = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe())[0]
else:
    fx = __file__


os_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(fx))
print(os_dir)
```

I was expecting to get my working directory but only got -

```
C:\Users\***\****Local\Temp\ipykernel_26840
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions out there is work with .env files. Those files need to be ignored in .gitignore and there, you can place your sensible information.

For example.

.env file:

```
DATA_PATH = '/home/user/data'
```

my_program.py

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()


CSV_FOLDER = os.getenv('DATA_PATH')

for file in os.listdir(CSV_FOLDER):
    print(file)
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        pd.read_csv(file)
```

You can even add conditions for the first if loop, like `if file.endswith('.csv') and file.startswith('data')` so you'll just load the file you want.

Using .env files will prevent you from hardcoding folder paths into your code, and revealing sensible information. In case you want to hardcode the folder path you need ot `CSV_FOLDER = os.listdir('/home/user/data')`